# Proving that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}=1$ implies $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, proof-explanation

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}=1$$ Then prove that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.
I was given this assignment and I'm not sure about my proof.. it feels like I'm assuming too much and not explaining with enough detail. Is there anything I need to add to make it sufficient?

Assume toward contradiction that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Then by definition we know that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Therefore

$\lim _{x\to 0}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)$

We know that

$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}=1$

Therefore we can conclude

$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \left|x\right|=1\cdot 0=0$

But we can also rewrite this as

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\cdot \frac{\left|x\right|}{\left|x\right|}=f\left(0\right)\cdot 1=0$

Therefore $f(0) = 0$.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ we have

$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x-0}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-0\right)}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}\cdot \frac{\left|x\right|}{\left|x\right|}=\lim \:\:_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}$

Since the one sided limits of $\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}$ exist, and are both equal to 1, we have

$\lim \:_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}\cdot \:\:\:\frac{x}{x}=1\cdot 1=1$

$\lim \:_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{-x}\cdot \:\:\:\frac{-x}{x}=1\cdot -1=-1$

Since the limit doesn't exist, we have a contradiction to the fact $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: Nee nor nee nor spelling police here. Please change all your "differential"s to *differentiable*.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Please use more specific, informative titles, like the one I have supplied. "Proof regarding differentiable functions" is very vague and generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks almost perfect to me. There's a couple of minor things I would change in the last few lines. You wrote:

> Since the one sided limits of $\frac{f\left(x\right)}{\left|x\right|}$
> exist, and are both equal to 1, we have
>
> $\lim \:_{x\to
>  0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot
>  \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to
>  \:0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}\cdot
>  \:\:\:\frac{x}{x}=1\cdot 1=1$
>
> $\lim \:_{x\to
>  0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot
>  \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to
>  \:0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{-x}\cdot
>  \:\:\:\frac{-x}{x}=1\cdot -1=-1$
>
> Since the limit doesn't exist, we have a contradiction to the fact $f$
> is differential at $0$.
>
> Therefore $f$ is not differential at 0.

I don't see the need to remove the absolute value signs in the following places in red:

$f'(0)= \lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x-0} = \lim \:_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\color{red}{|}x\color{red}{|}}\cdot \:\:\:\frac{x}{x}=1\cdot 1=1$, but

$f'(0) =\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)\right)}{x-0} =  \lim \:_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}\cdot \:\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{ \color{red}{|}x\color{red}{|}} \cdot \:\:\:\frac{-x}{x}=1\cdot -1=-1$

Since $\lim \:_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}$ only exists if both
$\lim \:_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}$ and $\lim \:_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}$
exist and are equal - which they aren't - we have a contradiction to the fact $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! At the beginning I thought about leaving the absolute value, but since I replaced the absolute value in the other expression I felt that I'm obliged to also do it in the main expression.. I thought it was the correct thing to do

Comment: Just because you changed $\frac{\left|x\right|}{x}$ to $\frac{x}{x}$ does not mean you are obliged to change $\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|}$ to $\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Assuming $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and since $f\sim \lvert x\rvert$ in a neigborhood of $0$, necessarily $f(0)=0$. Then taking the derivatives from both sides, you get the contradiction.